# how to remove dependency servlet-api from axis2 in gradle.build

Tags: servlets, gradle, dependencies, apache-axis

I have this dependencies tree in my gradle.
I have included `axis2-xmlbeans-1.6.1` in dependencies section. This makes my project also include `servlet-api-2.3` which I don't want.

I have tried to remove it from dependencies but it does not work.

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.apache.axis2:axis2-xmlbeans:1.6.1'){ 
            //exclude module: 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.3'
            exclude group: 'javax.servlet' , module: 'servlet-api'
    }
...
}
```

Result of `gradle dependencies`:

```
+--- org.apache.axis2:axis2-xmlbeans:1.6.1 [default]
|    +--- org.apache.axis2:axis2-codegen:1.6.1 [compile,master,runtime]
|    |    +--- org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:1.6.1 [compile,master,runtime]
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:1.2.12 [compile,master,runtime]
|    |    |    |    +--- jaxen:jaxen:1.1.6 [compile,master,runtime]
|    |    |    |    +--- .....
|    |    |    +--- javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.3 [compile,master,runtime]
```

Do you know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not good enough to replicate the issue. I ran `gradle dependencies` on this script:

```
apply plugin: "java"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.apache.axis2:axis2-xmlbeans:1.6.1') {
        //exclude module: 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.3'
        exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api'
    }
}
```

And there is no `servlet-api`. It's likely that the dependency gets in from a different configuration (maybe `master`, it looks like your custom configuration). You can try to eliminate it from there, or you can remove a dependency from all configurations:

```
configurations {
    master
    all*.exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api'
}
```

Comment: Your configurations ..master helps me to eliminate servlet-api. thanks. Also run gradle dependencies and see that servlet-api is only depending on axis2.